# How can I add a progress bar on a page in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app that calls an API procedure on the backend that does some database manipulation. This takes about 1 to 2 minutes, but the user screen has nothing on there.

Can I somehow have a progress bar that says what percentage it is up to? What could an example be?